# No network after changing static IP address on Alpine Linux on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, networking, static-ip, alpine-linux

I'm running Alpine Linux on Raspberry Pi. I'm trying to set a static IP address. So I changed the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` file from

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

to

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
    address 192.168.0.137
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

The contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` file are

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

After that I run

```
ifdown eth0
ifup eth0
```

aaaand I have no network. No matter what I do I can't connect to anything. I can't even ping the router. But if I reboot the device, suddenly everything works with the new IP address. The same goes for when I try to switch back to DHCP.

So my question is - any ideas why the new IP address works after reboot but not otherwise? What happens during reboot that helps, that doesn't happen with reloading the interface? I wanna make it work without the reboot. Thanks!

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

I was able to test it on my friend's network and it seems that it works fine there. It takes a while to catch up but eventually I can connect to the network and everything. It seams then, that it has something to do with my router, although I have no idea what it could be. I have TP-Link Archer C5.

**ADDITIONAL INFO 2**

I tried ifconfig as suggested here and at first I thought it works, because I got the new IP address and was able to communicate in LAN. But then I found out I still can't connect to the internet.

Comment: Do you have any network manager that may bew interfering with the normal interface startup? Have you tried to restart the entire netwoirking service (without using ifdown and ifup before or after))? (sudo systemctl restart networking) or the Alpine equivalent

Comment: I'm not aware of any networking manager. As far as I know there's just the networking service, which is basically just a script that runs `ifup` and `ifdown` commands. I tried to restart it too though, with the same effect.

Comment: Uhmm.. Then I have no idea. I know that old raspberry pis used internally a USB host to connect their wifi and LAN cards. If ifdown is causing it to dettach, then you won't be able to use it until restart, although I DOUBT this is the problem.

Comment: Anyway, you could manually change the file, THEN  use ifconfig to obtain the same effect without using ifdown / ifup. ifconfig changes are lost after reboot, but since you'll have manually changed your files, there won't be problems. Please, see https://www.tecmint.com/ifconfig-command-examples/ . Note that most modern systems have replaced ifconfig with newer alternatives, you can dig up a bit what is alpine currently using.

Comment: Please, let me know if ifconfig works and I'll write an answer later when I've some time to help others.

Comment: Yeah, ifconfig actually works like a charm. But check the original post, I added some more information that I found out over the weekend.

Answer (score 2):

The reason behind your problem is hard to tell without debuging the startup process, however, those are my best guesses:

- RaspberryPi 3 and below network cards are connected to the motherboard via USB. Ifdown may be causing it to enter in a enery state it is not able to recover from unless rebooted (this is probably NOT the cause).
- The Alpine distro is poorly ported to the Raspberry and ifdown is not properly shuting down the network card, leaving it in a non-recoverable state (either electrical or logical)

Posible solutions:

Restarting your network service instead. Although, as you said, it doesn't work in this case since it relies on ifdown / ifup

Command:

```
sudo systemctl restart networking
```

Use ipconfig to configure your network card without using ifdown / ifup. This settings are lost on reboot, so you'll still need to modify the files manually.

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.137 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: Indeed, ifconfig works! I guess it's a solution. However, I feel like there's something more interesting going on here. Check the original post, I added more info.

Answer (score 1):

Your `/etc/network/interfaces` doesn't look right to me.
Try this one

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.137
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

This defines your localhost as a loopback interface and defines `eth0` as a static interface with the same address, netmask, and gateway as your question.